# Java 8: Simplify and convert code to stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Code structure

```
public class Article {
   public String name;   
   public String description;
   public List<Translation> translations;
}

public class Translation { 
   public String field;
   public String value;
   public String language;
}
```

There is a method to transform and return specific result

```
List<Article> returnArticleswithCorrectTranslation(List<Article> articles, String language) {
    List<Article> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Article article: articles) {
        String languageCriteria = language;
        boolean isTranslationFound = false;
        for (Translation translation : article.translations) {
            if (translation.language.equals(language)) {
              isTranslationFound = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isTranslationFound) {
            languageCriteria = "en";
        }
        List<Translation> resultTranslations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Translation translation : article.translations) {
            if (translation.language.equals(languageCriteria)) {
                resultTranslations.add(translation);
            }
        }
        article.translations = resultTranslations;
        result.add(article);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Need an advice how can I convert that logic to Java 8 stream api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such questions are more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but ok, I'll answer.

First, even in previous Java versions there's no need to create the `result` list in the loop. The `result` is actually the same `List` as the input `articles` list as you don't create new objects, you modify the existing ones. Thus if you want to copy the original list (for whatever reason), you could write simply:

```
return new ArrayList<>(articles);
```

But probably you may omit the copying and return simply `articles`. Or even better change the return type to `void`. This way it will be more clear that your method actually changes the passed objects instead of creating the new ones.

To search whether the `Collection` has element matching the given predicate use `Stream.anyMatch()`:

```
String languageCriteria = 
        article.translations.stream().anyMatch(t -> t.language.equals(language)) 
        ? language : "en";
```

To filter the elements according to the given predicate use `Stream.filter()`:

```
article.translations = article.translations.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.language.equals(languageCriteria))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though it's likely that the original `article.translations` list is not used anywhere alse, and you can perform the filtering in-place using `Collection.removeIf()` instead of creating the `Stream` and separate `List`:

```
article.translations.removeIf(t -> !t.language.equals(languageCriteria));
```

So your method might look like this:

```
void filterArticleTranslations(List<Article> articles, String language) {
    articles.forEach(article -> {
        String languageCriteria = 
                article.translations.stream().anyMatch(t -> t.language.equals(language)) 
                ? language : "en";

        article.translations.removeIf(t -> !t.language.equals(languageCriteria));
    });
}
```

Further to encapsulate the `Article` modifications I would extract the loop body to the method of `Article` class:

```
public static class Article {
    String name;
    String description;
    List<Translation> translations;

    public void filterTranslations(String language) {
        String languageCriteria = 
                translations.stream().anyMatch(t -> t.language.equals(language)) 
                ? language : "en";

        translations.removeIf(t -> !t.language.equals(languageCriteria));
    }
}
```

Now your original method may look like this:

```
void filterArticleTranslations(List<Article> articles, String language) {
    articles.forEach(article -> article.filterTranslations(language));
}
```